# Is WAV (PCM) format bit rate is really CBR?

Tags: mp3, flac, wav, pcm, cbr

You know, all modern audio codecs bit rate modes are VBR, even if you restrict the settings to for example: MP3 128 CBR, the encoded result is between 120 to 135 ( a bit different with different encoders).
Even lossless codecs like FLAC bit rate is vbr.
What about PCM? Is this same?

Comment: WAV & AIF are the audio equivalent of a bitmap, one bit per bit.

Answer (score 0):

PCM (Pulse Code Modulation) is not a Variable Bit Rate.  ADPCM (Adaptive Digital PCM) is variable, but I don't know of any music applications that use ADPCM.  ADPCM has a higher bit-rate for the sine wave peaks, so it isn't used for high dynamic range applications like music, mostly voice.  WAV is linear with a 16-bit word (same as music CDs), which allows for 96 db. of dynamic range.